# Browser gets 206 Partial content error while downloading webfont under Windows 8.1

Tags: html, css, windows, apache

In any browser under Windows 8.1, fonts won't appear correctly on my website, because the webfont files for the website are not downloaded and the server gives only a 206 Partial Content error response. The error does not occur e.g. under Windows 7, no error message is given, the fonts are downloaded correctly. Is it a Windows-specified error or something else? The webfonts are in the same server and same subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this exact same error on my website. I don't believe it's a PC-specific issue, since I've seen this on my Vista PC and 7 PC. It might have something to do with the delivery of the font file. Here's what I did, which managed to fix it:

- Move font file to root directory
- Create an .htaccess file in the root directory (see bottom)
- Add extra lines of code to the apache2.conf file (see bottom)
- Lastly, reference the font in your CSS with **www**

---

**Example:**

*Do:*

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'familyName';
    src: url('//www.example.com/myfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

note the **www** above ^^ and removal of http: (removing the http: prefix helps when your site references by both http and https

---

*Don't do:*

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'familyName';
    src: url('http://example.com/myfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

---

Works in **Firefox** and **Chrome**, doesn't seem to in IE9. This also appears to fix the "font wont load on first webpage visit" issue where a font only loads on the second view of a website.

I haven't tested to see if it works without this, but ensure that you have a www CNAME record on your zone file.

---

***.htaccess file:***

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

***Extra lines for apache2.conf***

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Once you make the changes to your apache2.conf file, update and restart apache via

```
sudo a2enmod headers
sudo service apache2 restart
```